# Reopen a question which is on-hold

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions, close-reasons, reopen-request

I asked a question in workplace.stackexchange.com: [As a scrum master, how do I get everyone to take deadlines seriously?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/66745/how-to-increase-employees-engagement-during-work-in-a-software-company)

But unfortunately because of lack of information in the original version of the question I got many downvotes and also community putted my question on-hold situation.

I edited my question tens of times and I think its now a completely reasonable question and deserve a second chance to get more answers or at least re-open my question. Just wanted to know if there is any hope ?

I flaged the question for review and got the following answer:

> Declined. The moderators didn't put your question on hold; the
>   community did. Because you've edited, it should now be in the reopen
>   queue for review. You can also ask on meta or in chat about reopening.

Answer (score 4):

Your post has several problems that have not been resolved so I stand by my close vote:

- it's too long: long questions aren't by definition bad, but you're burying the lead, your title is meaningless and most of that information is unnecessary
- you don't have a single question:
- it's partly a popularity poll: "*Also please share any resources you think can be useful.*", "*I want to know what is your way/suggestion for me to increase employees engagement during work in such situtation.*" A question by definition asks for suggestions, but "What are some ways to X?" cannot be answered exhaustively.
- it's too broad: you can boil your question down to one or all of:

  - "how do I manage people?"
  - "how do I increase productivity?"
  - "how do I inrease employee engagement?"

The first 3 points can be resolved. The last one may make this unsuitable for the site. Those topics are incredibly broad and entire books have been written on the subject. We can answer questions with *practical answers*. That means a specific problem that has a solution that can be implemented. General advice or best practices can make great questions but require a clearly defined scope that is small enough to have reasonably comprehensive answers.

Answer (score 1):

From your original question:

> The problem begin when I first came into the team (its almost 10 days)
>   and from the first day I realized some of our employee's velocity is
>   lower than expected, work output is not on time and in overall some
>   times we are missing deadlines.

My biggest problem with the question is that in less than one sprint (10 days) you have decided that their velocity is not what you expect. And you are ready to implement a solution.

Now unless you were brought in because the management realized that the previous leadership wasn't able to get adequate performance out of the team,  and management knew exactly what the fix need to be; you haven't spent enough time with them.

Comment: This seems to be more of an answer to the original question, not this meta question.

Comment: You are right @mhoran_psprep , maybe I didn't mention it correctly but actually I have all past historical data and statistics of every single sprints so far and what I mentioned is based on 6 months historical data.